# VS setup project register search launch condition

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

Using a Visual Studio setup project (vdproj), I need to add a launch condition that checks for a registry value.

As you can see below I am checking for *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Search Company.\Software 2020 (64-bit)* and looking for value of *Path*.

[image]

The installer fails and looking at the windows installer log, I see that it is looking for *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32* :
MSI (c) (AC:30) [08:11:45:184]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\SOFTWARE\Search Company.\Software 2020 (64-bit) 3: 2

Why is it looking for the root HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32 and how can I handle this?

Comment: In Visual Studio, select your installer project. What is the value for "TargetPlatform"? X86, X64? Scroll down to see.

Comment: See the [RegLocator Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reglocator-table) in your finished MSI (use Orca or similar to check tables) - you must make sure the **`Type`** field has **`msidbLocatorType64bit`** set. And check this for more on 64-bit packages: [Using 64-Bit Windows Installer Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-64-bit-windows-installer-packages)